# OpenCV's findCirclesGrid isn't finding a grid of circles

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to perform a camera calibration with a grid of circles. I've been unsuccessful because `findCirclesGrid` always returns false even with a file that is nothing but a grid of circles. I've boiled it down to this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Mat image;
    // read an image
    if (argc < 2)
        image = imread("circleGridSmall.jpg");
    else
        image = imread(argv[1]);

    if (!image.data) {
        cout << "Image file not found\n";
        return 1;
    }

    imshow("image", image);
    waitKey(0);

    bool found;
    vector<Point2f> pointbuf;

    found = findCirclesGrid( image, Size(8, 12), pointbuf); 
    printf("found: %d\n", found);
    return 0;
}
```

And this simple image:

[image: grid of circles]

Even with this, `findCirclesGrid` returns false. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have inverted the `points_per_row` and `points_per_colum` in **Size()** function.
According to the documentation of function [findCirclesGrid()](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gac8fb88c7652a7699743aeb6073ef9b4a), 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter `patternSize` is

```
Size(points_per_row, points_per_colum)
```

Theferore:

```
// not 
found = findCirclesGrid( image, Size(8, 12), pointbuf); 
// but
found = findCirclesGrid( image, Size(12, 8), pointbuf);
```

Comment: That's the cause for this image but, unfortunately, that's not the only issue. My original image is 3264 x 2448. I shrunk it for this post. `findCirclesGrid` doesn't find the circles in the full-size image. So as a test I called `findCirclesGrid` on my photos after reducing them 75% and it found the circles. So apparently there is some undocumented maximum size image that it will work with or it's just a bug.

Comment: I did some tests and once the image got to 2448 x 1836 `findCirclesGrid` couldn't find any circles.

Answer (score 2):

If it works at one size and not at another, then your size filtering on the blobs is tripping you up. You need to create a custom blob detector, which you tweak with min size, max size, circularity etc.. (although size is probably the one affecting you), then pass the custom blob detector as an optional parameter into your  findCirclesGrid() function.

Anther thing I have found useful is to experiment with opencv and its python bindings. Turnaround time is a lot quicker than recompiling each time while you experiment with such things, then when you have it sussed out, you solidify the design into c++ code.