# Camera calibration with cv2.findCirclesGrid grid not detected

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm trying to calibrate one of our cameras, but having issues with the cv2.findCirclesGrid function.

The images are very low res and blurry, and that cannot be changed (due to the type of sensor we are using). I've attached a few sample images.

[Sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS8Zc.png) [Sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkYMO.png) [Sample3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9feT.png)

The cv2.simpleBlobDetector finds the circles well, and as the findCriclesGrid() function is based off that I'm surprised it doesn't work, especially using the same detector parameters. I've attached the same sample images but with the detected circles.

[Sample1_CirclesDetected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM5Xw.png) [Sample2_CirclesDetected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auU6x.png)  [Sample3_CirclesDetected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2lQq.png)

One thing I've noticed in the simpleBlobDetector is that the response of the keypoints remains 0.0 whatever the parameters I use. I'm wondering if findCirclesGrid() sorts or validates the keypoints according to their response?

Here is the code used for the the simpleBlobDetector():

```
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np
import logging

image = 'PathToImage'

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

im = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.minThreshold = 1
params.maxThreshold = 255

params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 50
params.maxArea = 300

params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.5

params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = .8

params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 7


detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Keypoint class: pt->coordinates, size->diameter, angle->angle of the blob, response->response showing the confidence of the proposition, octave, class_id
keypoints = detector.detect(im)

# Generate image
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255),
                                      cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
imgResized = cv2.resize(im_with_keypoints, (665, 500))

# find circle centers and size
circle_number = 12
point_centres = []
point_locations = []

"""gathers an array of the centrepoints of circles detected"""
for keyPoint in keypoints:
    x = keyPoint.pt[0]
    y = keyPoint.pt[1]
    s = keyPoint.size
    log.info(f'{keyPoint.response=}')

    pt = [x, y, np.sqrt(s / math.pi)]
    pts = [[x, y]]
    point_centres.append(pt)
    point_locations.append(pts)
```

Here is the code I use for the findCirclesGrid():

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
from find_circles import circle_centres
import logging

def main():
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)

    CHECKERBOARD = (3, 4)
    SquareSize = 72

    # Creating vector to store vectors of 3D points for each checkerboard image
    objpoints = []
    # Creating vector to store vectors of 2D points for each checkerboard image
    imgpoints = []


    objp = np.zeros((1, CHECKERBOARD[0] * CHECKERBOARD[1], 3), np.float32)
    objp[0, :, :2] = np.mgrid[0:CHECKERBOARD[0], 0:CHECKERBOARD[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)
    objp = objp * SquareSize

    log.info(f'objPts\n {objp}')

    fnames = 'PathToImages'
    images = glob.glob(fnames)

    params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
    params.minThreshold = 1
    params.maxThreshold = 255

    # params.filterByConvexity = True
    # params.minConvexity = 0.4

    params.filterByArea = True
    params.minArea = 50
    params.maxArea = 300

    params.filterByInertia = True
    params.minInertiaRatio = 0.5

    params.filterByCircularity = True
    params.minCircularity = 0.8

    params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 7

    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

    for fname in images:
        ret, centres = circle_centres(fname)

        img = cv2.imread(fname)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        ret, corners = cv2.findCirclesGrid(gray, CHECKERBOARD, None, flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_SYMMETRIC_GRID,blobDetector=detector)

        log.info(f'ret {ret}')

        if ret is True:
            imgCorners = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, CHECKERBOARD, corners, ret)
            resized = cv2.resize(imgCorners, (665, 500))
            cv2.imshow('Circular pattern', resized)
            cv2.waitKey()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: You can feed the detector to the circleGridFinder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703407/using-findcirclesgrid-in-large-images?rq=1

Comment: Isn't that what I'm already doing with this line? 
ret, corners = cv2.findCirclesGrid(gray, CHECKERBOARD, None, flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_SYMMETRIC_GRID,blobDetector=detector)

Comment: change your 3x4 to 4x3 patternSize: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37604259/2393191

Comment: Tried that beforehand as well, but does not help, unfortunately.

Comment: In the first link they say using cv2.CALIB_CB_CLUSTERING helped (edit2)

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I'll add an answer that links back to your comment (I can't seem to accept your comment as an answer).
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

So following Micka's comment, adding cv2.CALIB_CB_CLUSTERING to the flag did the trick!

```
ret, corners = cv2.findCirclesGrid(gray, CHECKERBOARD, None, flags=(cv2.CALIB_CB_SYMMETRIC_GRID + cv2.CALIB_CB_CLUSTERING),blobDetector=detector)
```